# Counting duplicates in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a list of postcodes that includes duplicates. I would like to find out how many instances of each postcode there are.

For example I would like this:

```
GL15
GL15
GL15
GL16
GL17
GL17
GL17
```

...to become this:

```
GL15 3
GL15 3
GL15 3
GL16 1
GL17 2
GL17 2
```

...or ideally this:

```
GL15 3
GL16 1
GL17 3
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to process the Excel sheet? Excel formulas? VBA? Processed by an outside app?

Comment: Just excel formulas at the moment.

Comment: same question is answered in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914063/i-want-to-give-same-number-to-the-duplicate-data-in-excel][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914063/i-want-to-give-same-number-to-the-duplicate-data-in-excel

i hope it will help yo

Comment: I think it's worth you take a look at following link: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-count-duplicates-and-unique-values-in-excel/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I don't know if it's entirely possible to do your ideal pattern. But I found a way to do your first way: CountIF

```
+-------+-------------------+
|   A   |         B         |
+-------+-------------------+
| GL15  | =COUNTIF(A:A, A1) |
+-------+-------------------+
| GL15  | =COUNTIF(A:A, A2) |
+-------+-------------------+
| GL15  | =COUNTIF(A:A, A3) |
+-------+-------------------+
| GL16  | =COUNTIF(A:A, A4) |
+-------+-------------------+
| GL17  | =COUNTIF(A:A, A5) |
+-------+-------------------+
| GL17  | =COUNTIF(A:A, A6) |
+-------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 23):

This can be done using pivot tables.
See this youtube video for a walkthrough: [Quickly Count Duplicates in Excel List With Pivot Table](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OlTsegp3cDY).

> To count the number of times each item is duplicated in an
>   Excel list, you can use a pivot table, instead of manually creating a list with formulas.

Answer (score 11):

1. Highlight the column with the name
2. Data > Pivot Table and Pivot Chart
3. Next, Next layout
4. drag the column title to the row section
5. drag it again to the data section
6. Ok > Finish

Comment: To clarify: this is the solution to your ideal scenario and works like a charm (just tried it) although my version of Excel has "Values" instead of "Data". Other than that, still a contemporary solution to an otherwise tedious problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can achieve your result in two steps. First, create a list of unique entries using Advanced Filter... from the pull down Filter menu. To do so, you have to add a name of the column to be sorted out. It is necessary, otherwise Excel will treat first row as a name rather than an entry. Highlight column that you want to filter (`A` in the example below), click the filter icon and chose 'Advanced Filter...'. That will bring up a window where you can select an option to "Copy to another location". Choose that one, as you will need your original list to do counts (in my example I will choose `C:C`). Also, select "Unique record only". That will give you a list of unique entries. Then you can count their frequencies using `=COUNTIF()` command. See screedshots for details.

Hope this helps!

```
  +--------+-------+--------+-------------------+
  |   A    |   B   |   C    |         D         |
  +--------+-------+--------+-------------------+
1 | ToSort |       | ToSort |                   |
  +--------+-------+--------+-------------------+
2 |  GL15  |       | GL15   | =COUNTIF(A:A, C2) |
  +--------+-------+--------+-------------------+
3 |  GL15  |       | GL16   | =COUNTIF(A:A, C3) |
  +--------+-------+--------+-------------------+
4 |  GL15  |       | GL17   | =COUNTIF(A:A, C4) |
  +--------+-------+--------+-------------------+
5 |  GL16  |       |        |                   |
  +--------+-------+--------+-------------------+
6 |  GL17  |       |        |                   |
  +--------+-------+--------+-------------------+
7 |  GL17  |       |        |                   |
  +--------+-------+--------+-------------------+
```

[image: Step 1][image: Step 2][image: Step 3]

Answer (score 3):

Say A:A contains the post codes, you could add a B column and put a 1 in each cell. In C1, put =SUMIF(A:A, A1, B:B) and Drag it down your sheet. That would give you the first desired result listed in your question.

EDIT: 
As Corey pointed out, you can just use COUNTIF(A:A, A1). As I mentioned in the comments you can copy paste special the row with formulas to hard code the counts, the select column A and click remove duplicates (entire row) to get your ideal result.

Comment: And of you want a consolidate report (your ideal answer), just copy paste special column B (by 'value') so you get rid of the formulas then highlight column A and click remove duplicates (remove entire row) and whalla!

Comment: This provides an unnecessary B column filled with 1s. My answer uses CountIf and works without that column.

Comment: Check out Corey's answer below as well. You might be able to just use countif that way there is no need to add the rows of 1s.

Comment: Aha Corey, we wrote at the same time. You are indeed correct.

Comment: Well I've done it now so I'm happy either way. However Corey's is slightly neater so he gets the points this time! Thanks both!

Answer (score 2):

If you are not looking for Excel formula, Its easy from the Menu

Data Menu --> Remove Duplicates would alert, if there are no duplicates

Also, if you see the count and reduced after removing duplicates...

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Select top cell of the data

Step 2 : Select Data > Sort.

Step 3 : Select Data >Subtotal

Step 4 : Change use function to "count" and click OK.

Step 5 : Collapse to 2

Answer (score 0):

If you perhaps also want to eliminate all of the duplicates and keep only a single one of each

Change the formula `=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)` to `=COUNIF($A$2:A2,A2)` and drag the formula down.
Then autofilter for anything greater than 1 and you can delete them.

Answer (score -1):

Let excel do the work.

1. Select column
2. Select Data tab
3. Select Subtotal, then "count"
4. DONE

Adds it up for you and puts total

```
Trinidad Count  99
    Trinidad Colorado
    Trinidad Colorado
    Trinidad Colorado
    Trinidad Colorado
    Trinidad Colorado
    Trinidad Colorado
Trinidad Colorado Count 6
    Trinidad.
    Trinidad.
Trinidad. Count 2
    winnemucca
    Winnemucca
    Winnemucca
    Winnemucca
    Winnemucca
    winnemucca
    Winnemucca
    Winnemucca
    Winnemucca
    winnemucca
    Winnemucca
    Winnemucca
    Winnemucca
    Winnemucca
winnemucca Count    14
```