# Excel counting columns

Tags: excel, excel-2010

[Counting duplicates in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875479/counting-duplicates-in-excel)

I want something very similar to the above. Consider input like

```
GL15
GL15
GL15
GL16
GL17
GL17
GL17
```

The above column is just one of the columns in a sheet. I want the output to be

```
GL15 3
GL16 1
GL17 3
```

I was hoping Pivot Table would solve this. So I added the column as a "Row Label" but I cannot get the count to work.

Please can someone provide some instructions?

Comment: Using `COUNTIF` wouldn't work there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here how to setup the Pivot Table:

[image]

Procedure:

1. Select data
2. Insert Pivot Table
3. Drag `Item` from Choose Fields list into Row Labels
4. Drag `Item` from Choose Fields list into Values (defaults to Count)

Comment: Seems like just what the doctor ordered, but what steps did you do to get there?

Comment: Exactly what I wanted !! The trick is to drag the "Item" column into the "Values".

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help ..

```
Salesperson Invoice
Buchanan    15,000
Buchanan    9,000
Suyama      8,000
Suyama      20,000
Buchanan    5,000
Dodsworth   22,500
```

Formula Description (Result)

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A7,"Buchanan")  Number of entries for Buchanan (result = 3)
=COUNTIF(A2:A7,A4)  Number of entries for Suyama (result = 2)
=COUNTIF(B2:B7,"< 20000")   Number of invoice values less than 20,000 (result = 4)
=COUNTIF(B2:B7,">="&B5) Number of invoice values greater than or equal to 20,000 (result = 2)
```

try like this,.
if you want some help tell .
I think this will help ..

Thank you...
Sampath Sri Anuradha
Web Designer and Developer