# I want to give same number to the duplicate data in excel

Tags: excel, duplicates, serial-number

I want to give same number to the duplicate data in excel

```
 A      B
apple   1
apple   1
apple   1
ball    2
bat     3
dog     4
dog     4
goat    5
```

Comment: i got the answer below is the right one stay away from voting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort your column `A` then insert the number `1` in cell `B2` and the following function in cell `B3` and copy down.

in cell `B2=1`

function in cell `B3`: `=if(A3=A2, B2, B2+1)`

***Update***

[image]

Comment: Not Working please try in excel

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to do it in a dynamic way that does not require sorting.

Paste the following formula in `B2` and copy down the column:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B1,MATCH(A2,A$1:A1,0)),MAX(B$1:B1)+1)
```