# Count duplicate values in a sequence

Tags: excel

How can I count duplicate data in a column using excel?

**Example**

```
  A     B
apple   1
apple   2
apple   3
ball    1
bat     1
dog     1
dog     2
gole    1
gole    2
gole    3
gole    4
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting duplicates in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875479/counting-duplicates-in-excel)

Comment: please check the example correctly that is not the answer

Comment: i got the answer its   =IF(A2=A1,B1+1,1)

Comment: Glad you got it working for your example. You could've also adapted the accepted answer to the question I considered a duplicate, though, and simply used `=COUNTIF(A$1:A1, A1)`, `=COUNTIF(A$1:A2, A1)`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no uniform formula for all cells in your case.

I would suggest something like this:
Put this on B column and then fill down the rest.

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1)
```

After you fill the other rows, values of rows would look like this

```
B1=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1)
B2=COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,$A2)
B3=COUNTIF($A$1:$A3,$A3)
```