# Count duplicate values in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a column filled with 0s and 1s like this:

```
A

1
1
1
0
0
1
0
1
1
0
0
1
0
0
1
```

What I want to do is simply have another column, with this values being counted until the next limit, like this:

```
A    B

1    1
1    2
1    3
0    1
0    2
1    1
0    1
1    1
1    2
0    1
0    2
1    1
0    1
0    2
1    1
```

I have searched for an answer, but I only found old posts and formulas that didn't work. This should be a simple thing. I only want one formula and I prefer to use only one column! I'm a noobie in Excel formulas.

Things I've tried but didn't work:

1. [Count duplicate values in a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961769/count-duplicate-values-in-a-sequence)
2. [Counting duplicates in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875479/counting-duplicates-in-excel)
3. [How do I count consecutive same values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625287/how-do-i-count-consecutive-same-values)
4. And other sources.

Comment: why not use a macro?

Comment: Because I'm an excel noobie :) Never used that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## steps as below

1. write cell `B1` with `1`
2. write cell `B2` with `=IF(A2=A1,B1+1,1)`
3. drag cell `B2` down

[image]

Comment: LOL I think I had this formula before... maybe did something wrong! Thank you!