# Running total for each day

Tags: r, excel

I need to create a running total for each day in excel or R Studio for this table and I cannot figure out how to do it. So for 2/28 it would start at 1 and then 2. Then for 2/27 it would start at 1 again and proceed down and so on restarting the total each day.

```html
Date         Total
2/28/2018 
2/28/2018 
2/27/2018 
2/27/2018 
2/27/2018 
2/27/2018 
2/27/2018 
2/27/2018 
2/27/2018 
2/27/2018 
2/25/2018 
2/25/2018 
2/25/2018 
2/25/2018 
2/25/2018 
2/25/2018 
2/24/2018 
2/24/2018 
2/24/2018 
2/24/2018 
2/24/2018 
2/24/2018 
2/24/2018 
2/24/2018 
2/24/2018 
2/24/2018 
2/23/2018 
2/23/2018 
2/23/2018 
2/23/2018 
2/23/2018 
2/23/2018 
2/23/2018 
2/23/2018 
2/23/2018
```

Comment: `transform(dat,Total=ave(Date,Date,FUN=seq_along))`

Comment: In excel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49441577/6202343

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` to do this.

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(Date=rep(LETTERS[1:5], each=c(4))) %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  mutate(Total=seq_along(Date))
```

So in your case, replace the `data.frame(...)` with your data.

Comment: You can use `row_number()` to be more tidyverse idiomatic

Comment: Sometimes I am to old school I guess :-) But you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `dplyr`

```
Date <- c("2/28/2018","2/28/2018","2/27/2018","2/27/2018","2/25/2018")  

df <- data.frame(Date)

df <- df %>% 
 group_by(Date) %>% 
 mutate(Total = seq_along(Date)) %>% 
 as.data.frame()
```