# How to give numbers to row that reset every time the value of another column changes?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, row

this is probably a simple question, but I want to create row numbers based on the values in the column.

It would look like this:

```
1 | AAA
2 | AAA
3 | AAA
1 | BBB
2 | BBB
1 | CCC
2 | CCC
3 | CCC
4 | CCC
1 | DDD
2 | DDD
```

I don't really know how to word my question since my first language isn't english, but what would be the function or steps to take to achieve that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961769/count-duplicate-values-in-a-sequence

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/631644/count-the-number-of-sequential-duplicates-excel

Comment: @BigBen Yeah the second one is perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that I found from @BigBen is this:

=IF(A2=A1,B1+1,1)

https://superuser.com/questions/631644/count-the-number-of-sequential-duplicates-excel